# Is the free version of OneNote like the full version of OneNote?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-onenote

My question is quite simple. Microsoft released a free version of OneNote, while there is still the paid version of OneNote. Where can I find the differences between this two versions?

For example, I can't save a notebook locally with the free version. I have to use the Microsofts cloud service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote ships with Office, so the free desktop versions are slightly trimmed down. All the core features are there, but the premium version of OneNote that you find in Office also has SharePoint support, Outlook integration and so on.... Few users exploit those features anyway, so the free edition should suit almost everyone. Take a look at the features when you purchase OneNote with Office 365 and compare to free version, hope this was helpful. 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/